# Laravel using paginate for relationship data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

in my web application each content as posts belong to one or many category and categories has many posts, now when i fetch data from with this code:

```
$categoryContents=ContentCategories::with('contents')->whereId($id)->latest()->paginate(10);
```

that's return this output:

```
    LengthAwarePaginator {#971 ▼
      #total: 1
      #lastPage: 1
      #items: Collection {#963 ▼
        #items: array:1 [▼
          0 => ContentCategories {#862 ▼
            #table: "contents_categories"
            ...
            #attributes: array:6 [▶]
            #original: array:6 [▶]
            ...
            #relations: array:1 [▼
              "contents" => Collection {#962 ▼
                #items: array:2 [▼
                  0 => Contents {#952 ▶}
                  1 => Contents {#953 ▶}
                ]
              }
            ]
            ...
          }
        ]
      }
      #perPage: 10
      #currentPage: 1
      #path: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/5"
      #query: []
      #fragment: null
      #pageName: "page"
    }
```

in this paginator i'm trying to show `contents` array on view by this code:

```
@foreach($categoryContents->contents_categories->contents as $content)

@endforeach
```

but i get this error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$contents_categories
```

how can i show this structure on paginator?

my models:

```
class ContentCategories extends Model
{
    ...

    public function contents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Contents::class);
    }
}

class Contents extends Model
{
    ...

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ContentCategories::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
$categoryContents=ContentCategories::with('contents')->whereId($id)->latest()->paginate(10);
```

doesn't make a whole lot of sense. You're querying for a `ContentCategory` by id, which will match exactly 1 result, but you're still using `latest()`, which orders (nothing to order on 1 row) the results and calling `paginate(10)`, which will paginate the result (nothing to paginate on 1 row).

You want to paginate the `contents`, not the parent `ContentCategories`:

```
// whereHas to scope it only to the category with id = `$id`
$contents = Contents::whereHas('categories', function ($subQuery) use ($id) {
        $subQuery->where('id', $id);
    })
    // Order the cotnents
    ->latest()
    // Paginate the contents
    ->paginate(10);
```

Then pass the `$contents` to your view and `foreach` over it:

```
@foreach($contents as $content)

@endforeach
```

Comment: could you help me to fix this error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Change the `categories` to the name of the `ContentCategories` table, probably `content_categories.id`

Comment: What about if you just do this: `$subQuery->where('id', $id);`

Comment: Did you pass it to the view?

Comment: may be this output help you: `select * from `contents_categories` inner join `content_categories_contents` on `contents_categories`.`id` = `content_categories_contents`.`content_categories_id` where `contents`.`id` = `content_categories_contents`.`contents_id` and `categories`.`id` = 5`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171429/discussion-between-aseeman-and-devk).

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this issue as the following:

```
  $categoryContents = ContentCategories::with('contents')->whereId($id)->latest()->paginate(10);
    $categoryContents->getCollection()->transform(function ($item) {
        return $item->contents;
    });
```